# R igraph: Barabasi-Model start.graph too many vertices

Tags: r, igraph

I have a large network, which I want to use as a "start.graph" for my Barabasi-Albert-Model, but unfortunately I get this Error.

> sample_pa(100, power = 1, m = 2, start.graph = large_network)
>   Error in sample_pa(100, power = 1, m = 2, start.graph = igraph_worm_traffic_colored[[1]]) : 
>     At games.c:519 : Starting graph has too many vertices, Invalid value

Is there any way to change the maximal number of vertices?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you need to have more vertices in your output graph than in your starting graph in order for the BA-model to work. You can take a subgraph of your large network if you want to use it to produce a 100-vertex graph.

```
 g2<-induced.subgraph(large.network, sample(V(large.network), 20))
```

Or you can increase the number of vertices in your output graph.